# Input select make a selection mandatory

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to make the selection a required field. I tried adding the required tag however that didn't help.

If the user doesn't select anything and clicks Submit, there needs to be some UI message to make them select an option from the dropdown.

```
 <Form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>

                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Select Report Type</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Input type="select" required name="reportType" id="reportType" onChange={(e) => this.setState({type: e.target.value})}>
                                        <option value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
                                        <option value={"Assignment"}>Assignment</option>
                                        <option value={"Intermediate"}>Intermediate</option>
                                        <option value={"Final"}>Final</option>
                                        <option value={"Raw"}>Raw</option>
                                    </Input>
                                </FormGroup>

                    </ModalBody>
                    {<ModalFooter>
                        <Button style={{fontSize:'14px'}} color="primary"  onClick={e => this.getReport(e)}>Submit</Button>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>}
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any specific reason for you to use the Input component, you could just use the [html select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) which supports the attribute required.

This would mean that you'd just replace `<Input type="select" ...` with `<select ...`

I am assuming that this is not a react-native app, as that wouldn't work there. (The code doesn't look like react-native code, but more like normal react web code.)

Comment: its react web code. However when I replace
<Select name="reportType" id="reportType" onChange={(e) => this.setState({type: e.target.value})}> I see the error Line 60:38:  'Select' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef. Any idea what might cause this? Thanks!

Comment: `<select>`, not `<Select>`

Comment: @ritaj is right. The native html tags do not start with capital letters. At this point they are really just plain old html.